# Sending mail with ASP.net causes AuthenticationException

Tags: email, ssl, asp.net-mvc-3, gmail, ssl-certificate

The site has been running for several years and now all of a sudden this error appears for many of the users of the site. The site is set up as MVC3 and at some point it is sending a mail to the user. Now the error appears:

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I find it hard to understand issues with certificates because I dont know enough about it. Since this is happening for several users if not all, I recon there is a problem with the SSL certificate on the server.? Could someone point me in the direction of solving this problem?

The application uses Gmail smtp server with ssl and authentication for sending mails.

And also I would be very happy if someone could explain shortly how the certificate procedures are :)

Comment: There are two ways to establish SSL connection with SMTP server: implicit (usually port 465) and STARTTLS (usually port 587). I recommend using STARTTLS instead of implicit SSL. If you want to test, you can use https://mailsnag.com or something similar. I use that and I dont get any cert errors. If you get cert errors on https://mailsnag.com then you might need to specify root CA cert on your client.

Comment: reference to SSL/STARTTLS https://sendgrid.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587/